# Samsung Pay not working with an Indian Card on a Galaxy Note 8 purchased in Hong Kong

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-8, samsung-pay

Don't know where to ask so asking it here.
I have an Galaxy Note 8 which was purchased from Hong Kong long back.
I want to use Samsung Pay on it but no Indian Cards are working.
I am pretty sure this is because of purchase location, because my dad has S10+ bought in India and S Pay works flawlessly with Indian Cards.
So is there any by which i can use S Pay

Comment: Which version of Android is the Galaxy Note 8 running?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Android version 9.